# What spider is this? Is this invasive or dangerous?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, arachnology

Hi the picture below has been taken [here](https://goo.gl/maps/QNwQmDbcVaGp1MYr9),

I've never seen such a spider, is it an invasive specie or a dangerous one?

[image: spider on grapefruit]

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be a zebra jumping spider (*Salticus scenicus*). It is fairly widespread throughout North America. It does not post any kind of threat to people or to the environment:

Here is a map of iNaturalist observations for zebra jumping spiders.
[image]

And here is a gallery of photos you can view: https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/68901-Salticus-scenicus/browse_photos